# VBA Code: Get element Value from the table received by HTTP response

Tags: excel, vba, http, web-scraping

I need your help to get element value from the Form received in HTTP Response.
Scenario: For example at the time of buying an stock, you click on button "BUY" of a particular stock. same time there would be a form open where you will fill all necessary details and place order. that form contains some hidden values like:"stk_token", "user_access", "user_id".. etc.
if i decode HTTP Response i can see those values(part of HTML Code as Received). please let me know if you required more information.

```
            </table>
            </div>
         </td>
        </tr>


 </table>


    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="stk_token" id="stk_token" value='1820'>
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="stk_me" id="stk_me" value='NN'>
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="stk_it" id="stk_it" value='EQ'> 
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="amo"  id="amo" value=0 >
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="so" id="so" value=0 >
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="order_buy_sell" id="order_buy_sell"  >
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="timestamp" id="timestamp" value="1549432660">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="client_id" id="client_id" value="M0KGI">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="oc" id="oc" value="">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="cover" id="cover" value="">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="mit" id="mit" value="">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="multipler" id="multipler" value="1">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="user_access" id="user_access" value="1021112110001000500011101001100000200110011001000000000000000000">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="key" id="key" value="F7E57EE9-A3BD-4804-9439-387FB8B0528F">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="stk_ltp" id="stk_ltp" value="211.35">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="orderdata" id="orderdata" value="">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="M84_153" >
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="client_group" id="client_group" value="M0KGI" >
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="branch_id" id="branch_id" value="FP" >
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="lsrc" id ="lsrc" value="0" >
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="wlsrc" id ="wlsrc" value="WEB" >
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="brckt_flag" id="brckt_flag" value="normal" >

    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="delivery_lot_comm" id ="delivery_lot_comm" value="0.00" >
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="price_den_comm" id ="price_den_comm" value="1.00" >




    </FORM>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/resources/trading/js/profile/default.js"></script>   <!--for main js-->
<div id="disp_footer" ></div>
<script>
```

I need to get all Id's Value on my sheet("order_buy_sell", "client_id"... etc). but if i am trying to print a single value its not working. Please help me in that. I have have spend much time to solve but not succeeded. This will be great help for me

```
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Cookie", cook

xmlhttp.send bodyR

html.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText

'---to get cookies-----
getcookres = xmlhttp.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
Worksheets("Action").Cells(3, 24).Value = getcookres
   Worksheets("Action").Range("X3:Z3").Replace What:="path=/; HttpOnly", Replacement:="", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'---cookies Close-----

'--- to get elements---

Dim ele As Object

Set ele = html.querySelectorAll("#user_access")

Debug.Print ele.Item.innerText

'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `querySelector` method as that returns a single element which is what is normally the case with using an id selector. `querySelectorAll` returns a nodeList which you have to index into.

```
Set ele = html.querySelector("#user_access")
```

Then, as it looks like you might actually want the value attribute, you can try with

```
Debug.Print ele.value
```

The other method for retrieval is to use

```
ele.getAttribute("value")
```

---

If you want all where `type` = `hidden`, and element is an `input` element, you could use an [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector in combination with a [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) selector:

```
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long
Set nodeList = html.querySelectorAll("input[type=hidden]")
For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
    Debug.Print nodeList.item(i).NAME, nodeList.item(i).Value
Next
```

Comment: ooh Its Done Now.. Thanks a lot...!!

Comment: node does have a .value attribute/property. But try the second approach.

Comment: sorry, there was typo error, now its working fine..!! but do i need to print every value per line..? or is it possible to get through loop..!!

Comment: I havetested by reading your html in from a desktop document. Both versions of my code work.

Comment: Which values are you after? A loop is almost certainly possible,

Comment: I have edited to show you how to get all where type = hidden and tag = input